# Setting CollapsingMode to OFF in xml

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How do I set `CollapsingMode` of view in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to "OFF" in xml?

```
app:layout_collapseMode="off"
```

is not working.

There's nothing about it in [developer references](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.html#COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF)